# Can't seem to connect to FTPS via Atom editor Remote FTP

Tags: ssl, ftps

I am trying to connect to my web server via my Atom editor, however whenever I try to connect with {"rejectUnauthorized": true,}, I received this error:

Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: myhost.com. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:dns.name

I can connect fine with the following code:

```
{
    "protocol": "ftp",
    "host": "myhost.com",
    "port": 21,
    "user": "username**",
    "pass": "password**",
    "promptForPass": false,
    "remote": "/",
    "local": "",
    "secure": true,
    "secureOptions": {"rejectUnauthorized": false, "requestCert": true, "agent": false},
    "connTimeout": 10000,
    "pasvTimeout": 10000,
    "keepalive": 10000,
    "watch": [],
    "watchTimeout": 500
}
```

However, from what I read, "rejectUnauthorized": false is not a very smart way to be transferring files. As it can cause a MITM attack.

I am using an automatically created Let's Encrypt SSL cert & Siteground for my hosting. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using an automatically created Let's Encrypt SSL cert & Siteground for my hosting. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I don't know the setup run by Siteground but my guess is that

- This is a shared hosting, i.e. you don't get a dedicated IP address for your domain but share it with others.
- The Let's Encrypt certificate is only installed for HTTPS (i.e. web access).
- With FTPS a single certificate is used on the IP address and thus is what you get. While with HTTPS it is is common to have multiple certificates per IP address by using [Server Name Indication (SNI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) this is usually not the case for other protocols like FTPS, SMTPS...

If my guess is correct then this is a shared FTPS server for all domains hosted on the system and the access to the users data is restricted by username+password and not by the domain name used to connect. In this case you are actually not expected to use your own domain name to access FTPS but you should use the common name (which is found in the certificate) and then login with your specific account.

It looks like that  this is even documented. From [Siteground FAQ: How to establish an FTP connection to your hosting account?](https://www.siteground.com/kb/establish-ftp-connection-hosting-account/):

> FTP Hostname - This is the **hosting server** name.

Thus, you are not expected to use your own domain name but the name of the hosting server.  This name can be found in your [Account Information](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/cpanel/account-information/).

Comment: You are a beautiful person. Thank you for this contribution. I changed to the siteground server name and it worked. However, my username was user@domain.com that I had set up for my email. Not the cPanel log in email. In case anyone else is trying to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone arrives here as I did looking for some guidance on how to connect from Atom to a SiteGround server when using one of their Cloud Hosting plans, here's how I did it...

My local workstation is a Mac.

I'm using the Remote FTP package for Atom: https://atom.io/packages/remote-ftp

Add an SSH key in SiteGround, Site Tools, Devs, SSH Keys Manager. You can also use that page to get a copy of the private key - put this in a text file on your local workstation.

In Atom, use the Remote FTP package menu to create an sftp config file. Here's mine:

```
{
    "protocol": "sftp",
    "host": "example.sg-host.com",
    "port": 18765,
    "user": "u30-xxxxxxxxxx",
    "remote": "/home/u30-xxxxxxxxxx/www/example.sg-host.com",
    "local": "",
    "agent": "env",
    "privatekey": "/Path/to/local/keyfile",
    "passphrase": "the password used when you created the siteground ssh key ",
    "hosthash": "",
    "ignorehost": true,
    "connTimeout": 10000,
    "keepalive": 10000,
    "keyboardInteractive": false,
    "keyboardInteractiveForPass": false,
    "remoteCommand": "",
    "remoteShell": "",
    "watch": [],
    "watchTimeout": 500
}
```

The thing that foxed me for a while is that the user you need to specify in the Remote FTP config file is the user in the SSH credentials. Maybe this is obvious to some. But it took me a while to realise you don't need an FTP user in SiteGround. SFTP is FTP over SSH so the SSH key and credentials are sufficient.

I'm using a temporary SiteGround domain name in this example. I think, although I haven't tested it, that if you've assigned a domain name to the SiteGround website, you would use that as the host.

The remote directory /home/u30-xxxxxxxxxx/www/example.sg-host.com is where you'll find the document root for the website, which on SiteGround is public_html.

Enjoy!