# Invalid SSL Certificate for Mail Server

Tags: ssl, openssl, smtp, certificate

Though this question is in the context of a particular software (Discourse forum software), it is really about SSL certificates of mail servers.

Here is my setup:

Main Website: **mydomain.com** (Hosted on Hostgator)

Forum Website (Discourse forum software): **forum.mydomain.com** (Hosted on DigitalOcean)

Mail Server (used by Discourse to send email to members): **mail.mydomain.com** (Hosted on Hostgator)

Discourse settings for SMTP:

```
DISCOURSE_SMTP_ADDRESS: mail.mydomain.com
DISCOURSE_SMTP_PORT: 587
DISCOURSE_SMTP_USER_NAME: forum-no-reply@mydomain.com
DISCOURSE_SMTP_PASSWORD: "mypassword"
DISCOURSE_SMTP_ENABLE_START_TLS: true           # (optional, default true)
```

I have SSL certificates set up for **mydomain.com** and **mail.mydomain.com** on Hostgator (A single SSL certificate for **mydomain.com** as well as several subdomains (like **mail.mydomain.com**, **webmail.mydomain.com**, etc)).

When I try to send a test email from the Discourse admin interface using the above settings, it gives me an '*invalid certificate*' error.

So, I tried to debug through openssl s_client with the following command:

```
openssl s_client -servername mail.mydomain.com -starttls smtp -crlf -connect mail.mydomain.com:587
```

It sends the SSL certificate of **mydomain.com** with CN as follows

```
subject=CN = mydomain.com
```

and establishes a SSL Session with TLS v1.2

Here are the weird results of EHLO after that:

```
EHLO mail.mydomain.com
250-xx-xx-xx.webhostbox.net Hello forum.mydomain.com [xx.xx.xx.xx]
250-SIZE 52428800
250-8BITMIME
250-PIPELINING
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250 HELP
```

As you can see with the second line in the above code, it responds from **xx-xx-xx.webhostbox.net** instead of **mail.mydomain.com** or **mydomain.com**

I think this is why I'm getting a '*invalid certificate*' error.

If I change the Discourse SMTP settings as below (just changing the first line)

```
DISCOURSE_SMTP_ADDRESS: xx-xx-xx.webhostbox.net
DISCOURSE_SMTP_PORT: 587
DISCOURSE_SMTP_USER_NAME: forum-no-reply@mydomain.com
DISCOURSE_SMTP_PASSWORD: "mypassword"
DISCOURSE_SMTP_ENABLE_START_TLS: true           # (optional, default true)
```

then everything works fine and all emails gets sent.

Could someone please let me know if this working solution is secure? I think it's not secure since I am using **xx-xx-xx.webhostbox.net** as SMTP address (which could expose the emails to risks) instead of **mail.mydomain.com**. If this is not secure, how should I proceed to get a secure solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [documented by Hostgator](https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/email-connection-settings) it is actually the correct setup to use the name of the hostgator server `full.servername.com` and NOT the name of your own domain `example.com` as the mail server. This is because the mail server is not specific to your domain but is a common mail server for multiple domains.

Note that this is very similar to [Can't seem to connect to FTPS via Atom editor Remote FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59475725/3081018) but only for SMTP not FTP. My explanation there can be applied to SMTP too.

Comment: Thank you v.much for your reply. I just have one doubt: I have also set up Windows 10 Mail app to access accounts on mail.mydomain.com. The SMTP (outgoing mail) settings for this are "mail.mydomain.com:465:1". Also, "Outgoing Server requires authentication" and "Require SSL for outgoing email" are checked. So how does Windows 10 Mail app (or any other mail client) make it work with mail.mydomain.com instead of full.servername.com?

Comment: @nparabz: Hard to tell, but it might be that you ignored already the warning about the wrong certificate. It will then not complain again.

Comment: Thanks v.much for the clarification. But I'm pretty sure I didn't ignore any warnings for wrong certificates. Because, when creating the accounts in Windows 10 Mail app, I just entered the username@mydomain.com and password. I didn't enter the mail.mydomain.com:465:1 part - the app just discovered it on it's own. Still, thanks again for your inputs. I will just wait for a few more inputs from other users (if any) and mark your answer as accepted.